# Calling a function declared in iframe and set on parent page

Tags: jquery, function, iframe

I want to put the content of an iframe into a div and then call a function declared in the same iframe but on the parent page:

```
$('#myframe').load( function(){
  var myfunc = this.contentWindow.iframefunc; <- the function is set successfully
  $('#mydiv').html( $($(this).contents()[0]).find('body').html() );
  myfunc(); <- not working
});
```

Comment: Is the iframe on a different domain? If so you're going to run into same-origin policy issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using eval:

```
$('#myframe').load( function(){
  eval( "var myfunc =" + this.contentWindow.iframefunc.toString() );
  $('#mydiv').html( $($(this).contents()[0]).find('body').html() );
  myfunc(); <- now works!
})
```